# Good practice / Bad Practice - Pointers and setting values - Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, pointers, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I'm still getting my head around pointers.  I've written the following code, and have my doubts about it's goodness.

I needed my view controller to be able to set a custom title for it's UIBarButtonItem depending on which new view controller it was going to push onto the navigation controller's stack.  Rather than having conditional code to check if self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem existed every time before I attempted to set it's new title (because by default, unless you create it, self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem is nil), I did this:

It works, but can anyone point out why I shouldn't do this:
I have a custom getter to lazily instantiate a navigation bar back button:

```
- (UIBarButtonItem *)myBackButton {
if (!myBackButton) {
    myBackButton =  [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:self.title style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil] retain];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = myBackButton;
}
return myBackButton;
```

}

Now in the rest of the .m file, whenever I want to change the title of the back button (eg before I push a new view controller onto the navigation controller's stack), I simply do:

```
self.myBackButton.title = @"Some Custom Title";
```

or:

```
self.myBackButton.title = self.title;
```

And I believe this works because self.myBackButton and self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem are pointing to the same object.  Is this type of indirect setting of objects advisable?  If not, what would be a better way to handing the bar button scenario?

Many Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Are you talking about the 'myBackButton' method?  This is a custom getter method for the instance variable 'myButton'.

Comment: Oops I suppose that comment should have said @Joe Blow

Comment: I think Joe was referring to the fact that you were returning a retained instance of `UIBarButtonItem`, but the name of the method didn't mention this fact. Obj-C/Cocoa static analysers (such as the one that comes with Xcode) will report your code as an error because it doesn't adhere to conventions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read Memory Management Guide to learn about alloc, retain, ...

You're allocating back button (= you own it) and you do retain it too (= you own it twice), thus you have to call release twice too.

No need to lazily instantiate back button, it's a small chunk of memory and I assume you do always want it visible. Better way is to do this in init method of your UIViewController.

Correct way is ...

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:self.title style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil] autorelease];
```

... to summarize memory management guide rules ...

- every method whose name begins with alloc, new, copy or mutableCopy creates an object, which is your (= you take ownership, you have to release it somewhere)
- if you want to release it (read relinquish ownership), you should call release or autorelease on this object, good practice is to set ivar to nil too

Comment: Ok, good call on not needing to lazily instantiate such a small item.  And since I instantiate it in the init for the view controller, I won't need any conditional code later to check if it exists before setting it's title.  Oh right, so custom getter was overriding a @property (retain), but because I used alloc instead of a autoreleased conveniece method, I don't need to retain to own it again.  Thanks, I get it now.

Comment: Any comment on whether it's a good idea to change the value of an object indirectly by accessing it through a different pointer to the same object?

Comment: It's just about readability of your code. If you set title property of self.myBackButton somewhere, how do you know it will really change back button's title at first sight? I can imagine it can confuse you sometimes. Why don't you access navigationItem property of your view controller before pushing? If you create your back button in init method of UIViewController, backButton will be available.

Answer (score 1):

you probably want to change that method to something like this.

```
- (UIBarButtonItem *)myBackButton {
    if (!myBackButton) {
        myBackButton =  [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:self.title style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil] autorelease];
    }
return myBackButton;
}
```

then, somewhere else(probably in your viewDidLoad/appear) call

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem= self.myBackButton;
```

I've changed the retain to autorelease, as any method with init, copy or new will incriment the retain count. if it doesn't contain init copy or new, it should return an autoreleased instance.

also when you set it to the backbuttonItem, it is retained by that anyway.

Its worth noting that when accessing properties through dot notation, you are actually going through the setters and getters. ie

```
self.myBackButton.title =@"title";
```

is the same as

```
[[self myBackButton] setTitle:@"title"];
```

You should almost always go through the setters and getters rather than accessing it as a local variable. i.e. use

self.myBackButton instead of myBackButton as this will allow you to do any required setup on the way through, and also to know that if any code is accessing it it will be going through that method rather than altering the variable directly.

Comment: I'm going with Chiefly Izzy's suggestion of scrapping lazy instantiation all together.  Thanks for your tips about dot notation too.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you're not clear about memory management rules, but more to your question: no, don't bother implementing this back button accessor, there already is a back button accessor and it's `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem`.

This method you've suggested is a lazy accessors, which you use when you have an object that isn't needed until the accessors is called. It hides the details of the object's creation to the callers who don't need to know.

However this situation the object, the button, is needed by the navigation view controller at the right time and should be created where it makes sense to. This is in a view controller, I think the button should be created either in init, loadView, or perhaps viewWillAppear. In this situation the details of the buttons creation *should* be explicit in whichever one of those location you have it in.

So take out that accessor, wherever you wanted to use `self.myBackButton.title` instead use `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem` and lastly make sure you initialize it in a place that's called before you ever have to access it (often your init).

Answer (score -3):

Your question boils down to this: What happens to the back button after it was pressed - when the view it controls is released. Check the retain count of your back button in these situations. If it remains stable, you're OK (assuming that no other modules in your program assign different back button instances). Otherwise, you will have to create a new back button each time you need one.

Comment: never look at the retain count of Obj-C objects. Always follow proper memory management guidelines and you won't have any issues.